# Laravel 4.2 Class not found error

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel-4

```
return Redirect::to('')
       ->with('message',SiteHelpers::alert('success','Password has been saved!'));
```

I am getting error in above line saying that

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   (E_UNKNOWN)
>
> Class 'SiteHelpers' not found

I kept SiteHelper.php in this path `/var/www/html/login_session/app/library`

Comment: did u add the `libarary` directory in autoload section in `composer.json`?

Comment: "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "app/commands",
   "app/controllers",
   "app/models",
   "app/database/migrations",
   "app/database/seeds",
   "app/tests/TestCase.php"
  ]
 },

Comment: I am having this code in my autoload section in composer.json

Comment: @SonuYadav you need to add "app/library" to that section. And don't forget to run `composer dump-auto` after that.

Comment: I added "app/library" in same section but still i am getting same error what more i have to do sorry for this silly question as m new to laravel

Comment: Done thanks for you answer i run composer install in my terminal and it worked out

Comment: cheerz :) , and you can remove this question, or you self answer this

Answer (score 1):

I added "app/library" in my composer.json and run composer install in my terminal